# Any difference between the varaible defined by the command line and the option in the `CMakeLists.txt`

Tags: c++, cmake

Here is the shell script which invokes the `cmake`

```
rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. -DWITH_FOO=ON
```

Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

option(WITH_FOO "whether FOO is enabled or not" off)

if(WITH_FOO)
    message("Attention! FOO is enabled!")
    add_compile_definitions(WITH_FOO_ENABLED)
endif()

add_executable(demo main.c)
```

Here is the content of the `main.c`:

```
int main(){return 0;}
```

Here is the output when the aforementioned shell script is called:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Attention! FOO is enabled!
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /data/Jhon/demo/build
```

Is there a variable named `WITH_FOO` that has ever been defined by the aforementioned command line(i.e. `cmake .. -DWITH_FOO=ON`)?

If the answer is yes, then does the  `option` also define a variable named `WITH_FOO` if the command line is `cmake ..` without `-DWITH_FOO=ON`?

Comment: "Is there a variable named `WITH_FOO` that has ever been defined ..." - You could easily check that with `if(WITH_FOO)` or even `if(DEFINED WITH_FOO)` placed in the corresponding line. "does the option also define a variable named `WITH_FOO` if the command line is `cmake ..` without `-DWITH_FOO=ON`?" - Yes, `option` defines a variable. But again, it is easily check that by your tests.

Comment: `option()` command is mostly equivalent to `set(... CACHE BOOL ...)` command, so you could find more cases in the [documentation for the latter one](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry).